# Get the value from a RichTextArea in a Selenium test

Tags: gwt, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to test with Selenium if a value has been loaded from the server in a RichTextArea in GWT.

I'm doing

```
@FindByDebugId("gwt-debug-about-me")
private WebElement aboutMeRichText;
```

When I send keys, there's no problem, the text is printed in the RichTextArea.

But when I try this (retrieve the value):

```
aboutMeRichText.getText()
```

it returns an empty String.

When I look at what's generated in the HTML, it's something like that :

```
<iframe class="GJUJXOPBLP-com-asdf-asdf-client-resource-Resources-Styles-textBox hasRichTextToolbar" id="gwt-debug-about-me">
#document
<html><head></head><body>Hi there !</body></html>
</iframe>
```

How should I do to retrieve the "Hi there !" text?

Comment: I've ran into a similar problem with GXT where fields I'm trying to retrieve have an attribute called "read-only" which when set I can't retrieve the text, sort of contradicts the attribute but nonetheless... do you happen to have anything like that?

Answer (score 1):

It's an `iframe`, which is not the same with normal `WebElement`, so you need to switch to it first.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(aboutMeRichText);
WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.TagName("body")); // then you find the body
body.getText();

// get out of the editor
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: @Oliver: Do you have any feedback on this? Did it work for you?